# I dont want to add UInavigationController and tabbarcontroller on root view controller

Tags: ios

I have a single view based app, when it runs it shows 2 button. On tap of 1 button i want to switch to another view which must be uinavigationcontroller and on 2 button i want to switch to tabbarcontroller view. I know what uinav and tabbar controllers can do. I created uinav and tab based project and study all the code, searched on internet for tutorials but what i get is everyone telling to add like this

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

on rootviewcontroller.

I **dont** want to add UInavigationController and tabbarcontroller on root view controller. Please help me solving this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Then create a `UIViewController` called RootViewController for example, add two buttons inside its view and handle the touch events for those buttons. The first button, when touched should present your UINavigationController and the second button should present your UITabBarViewController. Then in your AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method initialize your RootViewController and set the self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;

**(UPDATE)**
Allright, create a SingleView application. Put the buttons and set up the outlets and actions for those buttons. You also need to create 2 more view controllers: one UINavigationController and one UITabBarController. When the first button is touched, in the method which handles the touch add:

```
-(void)button1Touched:(id)sender
{
    MyNavivationController *navc = [[MyNavigationController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:navc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

You can do the same with the other button, but there initialize your tab bar controller and do the same. If you are unfamiliar with those operations you may refer to the documentation on how to create view controllers, handle events and etc...

Answer (score 0):

@pamy I can provide you complete source code please let me know your skype id or other way to send you the file, i don't know how to post the code on stackoverflow.

I did write many times but it's not accepting my code.